# Using a html form to search and retrieve data from mysql workbench by php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database using and HTML form and php connection to my sql-workbench.  I have a successful connection to the data base and my retrieval is posted at the top of my webpage. I'm not sure how to get it to run the sql query on the submit form function.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head data-gwd-animation-mode="quickMode">
    <title>Test_webpage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="Google Web Designer 1.1.3.1119">
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
  
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "006";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
        //$con->close();
        //$query = "SELECT * FROM US_Cars";

 if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Manufacturer,VIN,Color,Model,Fuel_Type,State_of_Origin FROM mydb.US_Cars;";
$result = $con->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Manufacturer: " . $row["Manufacturer"]. " VIN: " . $row["VIN"]. " Color:" . $row["Color"]. " Model:" . $row["Model"]. " Fuel Type:" . $row["Fuel_Type"]. " State Location:" . $row["State_of_Origin"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>




    <div id="first">
      <p>Enter Criteria Below to Search.</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="second">
      <p class="gwd-p-j2b6">Select a Manufacturer</p>


<!-- start of form -->
      <form class="gwd-form-yuwo" method="post" action="<?search2.php ?>">
      <select class="auto-style3 gwd-select-u9g0">
            <option value="GM">GM</option>
            <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
            <option value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
            <option value="Tesla">Tesla</option>
      </select>appreaciated
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="gwd-p-cy97">Select a Dealership Location</p>
      <select class="auto-style3 gwd-select-dkho">
        <option value="">Virginia</option>
        <option value="">Maryland</option>
        <option value="">New Jesery</option>
        <option value="">Kentucky</option>
      </select>
      
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="auto-style2">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      <img id="pic1" src="page2_1.jpg" style="width:500px;" height="236px" >
    </div>
    <div id="forth">
      <img src="tesla.png" style="width:125px;height:250px">
    </div>
    <div id="fifth">
      <footer>
        <p>
          <a href="">U.S. Car data Entry</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="">About Page</a>
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, `action="<?search2.php ?>"` that's questionable. This `action="<?php search2.php ?>"` could be modified as that, if short tags are not set. If you're wanting to retrieve from DB, you'll need to assign POST variables and name your form elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="gwd-form-yuwo" method="post" action="<?search2.php ?>">
```

is your issue.. pretty sure that is supposed to be

```
<form class="gwd-form-yuwo" method="post" action="search2.php">
```

which would send you to search2.php when the submit button was pressed... then in search2.php you would get your form values from $_POST and then run your query.

That being said I think that is not what you are trying to do and what you really want to do is update a list of things within the webpage without linking through. i.e. on button press update html at top of page to list query results using prams from form.  If that is what you are trying to do you are way off and need to look up ajax... your submit button would not have a direct action but instead run a javascript fuction that would send an ajax request to search2.php that would run the query and then your java script would update innerhtml on response.